# Why can't I call CheckTerminated on an externally created thread?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When I run this code:

```
  FMyThread := TThread.createAnonymousThread(
   procedure
   begin
     while not FMyThread.CheckTerminated do begin
       sleep(750);
       TThread.synchronize(nil,
         procedure
         begin
           if FMyThread.CheckTerminated then exit;
           ....
         end);
     end;
   end);
   FMyThread.start;
```

I have the exception

> Cannot call CheckTerminated on an externally created thread

Why ?

Comment: Check [this](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=700438) page, I think it can help you

Comment: On a side note, it's very risky to keep a reference at all to an anonymous thread and expect to use it. Once you start it, it's meaningless because the thread could be terminated by the time you want to use it. Instead, just use `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread( ... ).Start;` all in one call.

Comment: I suspect there is a misunderstanding here. What is your goal when you call CheckTerminated?

Comment: The simple solution would be to not rely on it from within the `Synchronize`, which should only have minimal code with very short execution time. After all, that's the primary idea behind threads in the first place, to keep the main thread responsive. If you're concerned about the thread being terminated in a `Synchronize`, then you need to re-think your design. Such checks should be done in the context of the actual thread itself, not in a `Synchronize` (main thread). Personally, I see zero reason why anyone would want this information within `Synchronize`.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the implementation of CheckTerminated, you will notice it's not a method but a static class method.

`CheckTerminated` indicates if the currently executing thread has its `Terminated` flag set to `TRUE`. When you call FMyThread.CheckTerminated inside TThread.synchronize, , it doesn't check FMyThread.Terminated, it tries to check the state of "GetCurrentThreadId", which in this case is your process' main thread.

Since the main thread isn't created by a TThread, the RTL creates a `TExternalThread` (See `class function TThread.GetCurrentThread: TThread`)

In other words, if you have a TThread object and want to check whether it's terminated or not, you should call `Terminated`, not `CheckTerminated`.

Since AnonymousThread are by default freed on terminate, you need to make sure you clear any reference to your thread in a `OnTerminate` handler.

Comment: but terminated is protected under XE2 and I can not access it :(

Comment: @Stephane You didn't mention XE2 in your question. I've added the tag for you. As a rule of thumb, if a question doesn't have a specific version, it's assumed to be the latest current version. You may be better off just creating an inherited `TThread` object. Especially if you intend for it to do any sort of long running task.

Comment: @Stephane you can use an accessor class to reach a class's protected members from outside the class, eg `type TThreadAccess = class(TThread) end; ... if TThreadAccess(FMyThread).Terminated then ...`

Comment: @Stephen I thought as much. CheckTerminated does not do what you think it does. The solution to your problemndoes not involve calling CheckTerminated.